# Como gerar palpites não repetidos para o jogo da mega sena?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa Noite! Sou bem iniciante em Python e estou tentando implementar uma função que gera números a ser utilizados em jogos da mega sena. Porém, quando executa a referida função ela me retorna o seguinte:

```
[54, 38, 32, 54, 38, 28]
```

Observe que o retorno da função é formado por uma lista contendo alguns valores repetidos.

Gostaria de evitar números repetidos. Como posso proceder?

**Código**

```
from random import randint
 
 
def gerar_seis_numeros():
    numeros = []
    for i in range(6):
        numeros.append(randint(0, 60))
    return numeros
 
 
def completar():
    return randint(0, 60)
 
n = gerar_seis_numeros()
for i in range(6):
 
    if n[i] != n[i]:
        print(completar())
```

Comment: Luiz Machado, em primeiro lugar seja bem vindo à plataforma. Em segundo lugar, se pretendes gerar sorteios de números a ser utilizados como palpites de jogos da Mega Sena, utilize o método `sample` de biblioteca `random`. Leia também [Manual de Como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1). Abraço e volte sempre.

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar um algoritmo que seja capaz de gerar palpite de jogo da `Mega Sena`.

Pois bem, como falei no comentário acima, devemos utilizar o método `sample` da biblioteca `random`.

Um possível código seria:

```
from random import sample


def mega_sena(q):
    for i in range(1, q + 1):
        yield sorted(sample(range(1, 61), 6))


quant = int(input('Quantidade de palpites: '))

for j in mega_sena(quant):
    for k in j:
        print(f'{k:02}', end=' ')
    print()
```

Observe que quando executamos o código, recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Quantidade de palpites:` . Neste momento devemos digitar a quantidade de palpites para o jogo da Mega Sena. Em seguida, esta quantidade é repassada para a função `mega_sena(q)`. Chegando lá o bloco **for** irá percorrer o range formado pela quantidade de palpites e, para cada interação `i`, com o auxílio da função **yield**, será formado um gerador formado pelos **6** valores sorteados e **não repetidos**, dentro do **range(1, 61)**.

**OBS:** como queremos sortear os valores entre [1, 60] devemos utilizar o **range(1, 61)**.

Posteriormente serão exibidos os resultados de cada palpite.

Comment: Poderia explicar o que exatamente esse `print(f'{k:02}', end=' ')` faz?

Comment: obrigado aos dois por me ajuda.

Comment: @yoyo, o `print(f'{k:02}', end=' ')`, serve para imprimir cada número com dois algarismos na mesma linha. Os números que não tem dois algarismos `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`, são completados com um zero à esquerda, ficando `(01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 09)`.

Answer (score 2):

Olá você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
from random import randint

def gerar_seis_numeros():
    numeros = []

    while len(numeros) < 6:
        # Executando o random
        x = randint(0, 60)
        # verificando se o numero existe na lista, caso exista não é adicionado
        if x not in numeros: numeros.append(x)

    return numeros

x = gerar_seis_numeros()
print(x)
```

Comment: Se você quer que a função rode o suficiente para adicionar 6 números diferentes à lista, não há necessidade de usar um range até mil e adicionar um if. E se o `randint()` gerar números iguais por mais de mil vezes seguidas? a função vai parar mas a lista não estará completa. Nessa situação o ideal é usar um `while len(numeros) < 6:`

Comment: @yoyo corrigido!

Comment: obrigado, bem legal sou bem iniciante nisso